# How to receive Firebase Fatal or any reports to multiple users?

Tags: android, firebase, crashlytics, crashlytics-android

I have integrated a *Firebase crash report* inside the Android App and I am also getting a crash report for my account.

But I want to know that Is there any possibility to receive the same crash reports (Fatal or non-fatal, etc.) **to multiple users**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is a way to achieve this.

**`Assign a proper role to the users:`**

Assign any below roles to that user

1. [Firebase Quality Admin](https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/iam/roles-predefined-category#quality_roles)
2. [Project owner](https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/iam/roles) or
3. [Editor](https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/iam/roles)

Now, The below steps need to be ***performed to that assigned users***:

1. Go to [firebase console](https://console.firebase.google.com/u/1/)
2. Click on the bell icon at the top-right corner
3. Select your project from the dropdown list
4. Click on "Manage your alerts"
5. Scroll down to "Crashlytics" section
6. Select the checkbox under the email column to receive email notifications.